# div is displayed centered in Firefox, but not in IE

Tags: css, google-maps

I'm trying to align a **div** (used for Google Maps) in [page](http://preferans.de/user.php?id=DE2) center by setting **margin-left** and **margin-right** to **auto**, but this only works with Firefox, but not with Internet Explorer:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    h1,h2,h3,p { text-align: center; }
 #map { width: 700; height: 280; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function init() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
 var opts = {
  zoom: 9,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), opts);
}

</script>
<head>
<body onload="init();">
<h3>Map</h3>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anybody please know, how to center the **div** in IE as well?
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a doctype, `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` before anything to trigger standards mode.

Comment: Thanks, placing <!DOCTYPE HTML> before <HTML> has helped, I had to change width: 700 to width: 700px though

Comment: ah, didnt spot the `700` without px, yeah always specify a unit unless it is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    div#container { width: 700px; text-align: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
    #map { width: 700; height: 280; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function init() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var opts = {
        zoom: 9,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), opts);
}

</script>
<head>
<body onload="init();">
  <div id="container">
    <h3>Map</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Should do it. And as Meder states: Always use a doctype!