# Main Content Div in Not Centered In IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Why is the main content division in not centered in IE (although it is centered in Firefox and Chrome). The website URL is: [website](http://consumer.myjoice.com/uk/).

I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355142/div-is-displayed-centered-in-firefox-but-not-in-ie) question on SO, but I couldn't resolve the issue.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Used to this Css**

```
body{
text-align:center;
}

#main{
text-align:left;
}
```

**[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NM8L.jpg)**

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your page is going into quirks mode. Although @Rohit's answer solves (**hides**) the issue, you should use the following as your `DOCTYPE` declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

And *if* the above isn't enough, add the following `meta` tag as well (inside your `head`):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

This will prevent IE from going into quirks mode.